# SQL connection in Grails

Tags: sql, grails, connection-string

In my application there are a few places where I want to use pure SQL. When I hard code the connection details in Sql.newInstance it works fine. For obvious reasons I would prefer to not hard code the connection details.

When I use the dataSource variable it comes up as null. My code in the controller is:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def dataSource
def sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource)
sql.executeInsert("insert into....")
```

My code in the datasource config file is:

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" 
            url = "jdbc:postgresql:mydev"
            username = "xxx"
            password = "xxx"
```

As you can see I'm using PostgreSQL. I've also tried it using the default grails database with the same results.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `dataSource` outside of your controller action. Otherwise spring cannot do the required dependency injection for you:

```
class YouController {

    def dataSource

    def yourAction() {
        def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
        [..]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi crudolf Thanks for the answer. It now passes this def dataSource line, but when I set def sql = new Sql(dataSource) I get a ClassNotFoundException exception. I've also tried def sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource), but the same result. Any ideas? Regards, Marius

Comment: try to do `import groovy.sql.Sql` in the top of your controller. Theoretically it should work. Are you using grails 1.3.7 or 2.0.1? If it doesn't help please tell me the complete exception reason.

Comment: I am using grails 2.0.1. Currently I am importing groovy.sql.Sql. I have an idea why it is not working, but do not know how to fix it, or if it is even the issue. In my view I use a tag to render some checkboxes. On checking / unchecking these checkboxes I use an AJAX call to pass some parameters to a javascript function, which in turn calls the controller where I have a custom action where I try to run the SQL query. Could it be that I lose my grails objects when using the AJAX call?

Comment: Could you give us the concrete ClassNotFoundException? Whether it is an AJAX call or not, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I do not know what the issue was, but changed my code from `def sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource)` to `groovy.sql.Sql = new groovy.sql.Sql(dataSource)` and it now works fine. Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.